# netty 4; how to initialize client's connection from same thread synchronously

Tags: single-threaded, netty4

this seems to be simple but I am stuck.

I have a netty server that is configured with single eventLoop, in this event loop I want to connect to other server and I am initializing connection on that eventLoop, also this eventLoop is passed to a client as a worker group, so everything is performed on single thread.

```
ChannelFuture connectionFuture = b.connect(host, port);
```

I cannot use sync() on the future, as this would block the given eventLoop and fail.

unfortunately the `#connect()` pushes connection task to be resolved later even though it realizes the connection is performed on the executor thread already.

```
    private static void doConnect(
            final SocketAddress remoteAddress, 
            final SocketAddress localAddress, 
            final ChannelPromise connectPromise) {

        // This method is invoked before channelRegistered() is triggered.  
        // Give user handlers a chance to set up
        // the pipeline in its channelRegistered() implementation.
        final Channel channel = connectPromise.channel();
        channel.eventLoop().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (localAddress == null) {
                    channel.connect(remoteAddress, connectPromise);
                } else {
                    channel.connect(remoteAddress, localAddress, connectPromise);
                }
                connectPromise.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE_ON_FAILURE);
            }
        });
    }
```

and I dont see a way to let event loop to perform any action it needs to initialize a valid channel.

calling `SingleThreadEventExecutor#runAllTasks()` could be a way to go, but channel is not active after that :/